# Coerce command('stdout') to integer for math comparison

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen, inspec

Given a checker script deployed to my server at path `/tmp/foo` with the following content...

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`cat /tmp/a`
b=`cat /tmp/b`
echo -n $( expr $a - $b )
```

...I have an InSpec test to evaluate if the difference between a and b are within an acceptable range.

```rb
describe command('/tmp/foo') do 
  its('stdout') { should be >= 0 }
  its('stdout') { should be < 120 }
end
```

Sadly, the `be` [matcher](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/matchers/) won't coerce the input to a type that can be used with the math operators.

> How can I coerce this value to an integer?

---

So far I've tried

- `('stdout').to_i`

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<Class:0x00007f8a86b91f00> (NoMethodError) Did you mean?  to_s
```

- `('stdout').to_s` and `('stdout').to_s.to_i`

```
   Command: `/tmp/foo`
     ↺  
     ↺  

Test Summary: 0 successful, 0 failures, 2 skipped
```

- `(('stdout').to_i)`

```
undefined method `0' for Command: `/tmp/foo`:#<Class:0x00007f9a52b912e0>
```

For background, `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/b` are a pair of epoch outputs from a previous InSpec test.

I could check client side if the values are within the acceptable range, but if possible I would like to have this variance checked & reported by the InSpec evaluation without regex wizardry in place of human-readable math expression.

Comment: I am not familiar with InSpec at all, but it seems obvious that you have to look at its documentation and see how you can get access to the standard output of the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [`@bodumin`](https://chefcommunity.slack.com/archives/C1XB6U6MN/p1568129617142800) in the [chef community slack #InSpec channel](https://app.slack.com/client/T0M1PBN4E/C1XB6U6MN)

> Fuzzy typing with `cmp` matching

The simplest solution is to use the `cmp` matcher instead of the `be` matcher. While there are no explicit math operators given by example on [the official docs for `cmp`], math operations within a `cmp` match will evaluate properly

```rb
describe command('/tmp/foo') do 
  its('stdout') { should cmp >= 0 }
  its('stdout') { should cmp < 120 }
end
```

Per [`@aaronlippold`](https://chefcommunity.slack.com/archives/C1XB6U6MN/p1568130398147200)

> `cmp` is a logical compare that we do in the backend … aka 1 is true is TRUE is True. So in SSHD config as an example … you can set a prop using 1 or true or TRUE or True etc. Its a more forgiving matcher that we have built as much as a convince function etc.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to `@cwolfe` in the [chef community slack #InSpec channel](https://chefcommunity.slack.com/archives/C1XB6U6MN/p1568132773163200)

> Exact typing with `be` matching and method chaining

Another approach is to try method chaining within the `stdout` literal like this:

```rb
describe command("bash /tmp/foo") do 
  its('stdout.strip.to_i') { should be >= 5 }
end
```

InSpec uses the [rspec-its library](https://relishapp.com/palfvin/rspec-its/docs/attribute-of-subject#specify-value-of-a-nested-attribute), which interprets dots as method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to `@aaronlippold` the [chef community slack #InSpec channel](https://app.slack.com/client/T0M1PBN4E/C1XB6U6MN)

> Exact typing with `be` match & explicit subject syntax

The `stdout` of the InSpec `command` can be cached outside of the `describe` block and modified arbitrarily. Here we ask InSpec to run the script, grab its `stdout` and strip the line (`\n`), then look at the result and ensure it is between the expected values using the `be` matcher syntax for strict type comparison.

```rb
x = inspec.command("bash /tmp/foo").stdout.strip.to_i

describe x do 
  its { should be >= 5 }
  its { should be < 10 }
end
```

Alternately, you can use the [rspec explicit subject syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/explicit-subject) to pull the return value out to make it more clear in the code.

```rb
describe "The value of my EPOC is between the required values" do
  subject { command("bash /tmp/foo").stdout.strip.to_i }
  it { should be >= 5 }
  it { should be < 10 }
end
```

This also allows you to better report to the “what” vs the “how” as well.

Another syntax option for this approach uses `puts()`

```rb
cmd = command("bash /tmp/foo")
puts(cmd.inspect)
describe cmd do 
  its('stdout') { expect(cmd.strip.to_i).to be >= 5 }
end
```